# ATA controller on SATA hard disk

Tags: sata, ata

I have a small ATA disk, a big SATA disk, and an old computer that supports only ATA. Can I unscrew the ATA controller from the disk and attach it to the other disk?

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't. The electronics to control the drive, and the firmware are on the controller card, and you can't just swap them willy nilly between systems.

You *could* get a adaptor to use the SATA disk with a pata connector however.

Comment: He can Google for "SATA to PATA adapter" and find what he needs.

Comment: precisely. as opposed to hacking apart something in the vain hope that it works